# Array returning null value

Tags: java, arrays

I'm getting a little confused with Arrays and was hoping that someone could help me out.

I hope this makes sense because I am a bit confused. Any help is much appreciated!

The while loop creating the objects in class 'League'

```
     while (lineScanner.hasNextLine())
       {
       currentLine = lineScanner.nextLine();
           String[] newSSs = currentLine.split(","); 
           Team team = new Team(newSS[0]);
           team.setWins(Integer.valueOf(newSS[1]));
           team.setDraws(Integer.valueOf(newSS[2]));
           team.setLoses(Integer.valueOf(newSS[3]));
           team.setPoints(team.calculatePoints());
```

Comment: I'm too a bit confused... Where are the `ArrayList`s in your code?

Comment: Can you post more code? It's not clear from the code you posted what the problem is. I see no ArrayList in that code.

Comment: Still I don't see the `ArrayList`... I think you should post more of your `League.class` (and most likely the stuff you have around your while loop)

Comment: In my League class I have "private Team[] teams;"  If I add an ArrayList I get 2 Arrays (one from class Team) and one from the ArrayList. The ArraList gets all the information and the Array from class values all return as null. Also thank you so far, I'm completely new with this!

Comment: All of the answers are saying replace private Team[] teams with private ArrayList<Team> team.  Are you just dead set on using an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I know what you're trying to do...
Create one ArrayList before your while loop (you need a collection of some kind to store your parsed teams):

```
private ArrayList<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>();

while (lineScanner.hasNextLine()){
    currentLine = lineScanner.nextLine();
    String[] newSSs = currentLine.split(","); 
    Team team = new Team(newSS[0]);
    team.setWins(Integer.valueOf(newSS[1]));
    team.setDraws(Integer.valueOf(newSS[2]));
    team.setLoses(Integer.valueOf(newSS[3]));
    team.setPoints(team.calculatePoints());
}
```

You really have just one array - the one that holds teams. Lifetime of newSSs is limited to one pass through the loop and once lineScanner does not have more lines to process, the loop ends and newSSs is disposed of.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing:

```
  ArrayList<Team> list = new ArrayList<Team>();
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
     list.add(null);

   //change values
    list.set(0,new Team(newSS[0]);
    list.get(0).setWins(Integer.valueOf(newSS[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you Team class has the following methods -

```
setWins()
setDraws()
setLoses()
setPoints()
```

But here you are trying to use these method form a `Team team` which you have declared as an array -

```
Team team = new Team(newSS[0]);
```

Since here `team` is a array of `Team` try to do this -

```
team[0].setWins(Integer.valueOf(newSS[1]));
team[0].setDraws(Integer.valueOf(newSS[2]));
team[0].setLoses(Integer.valueOf(newSS[3]));
```

Comment: Team team = new Team(newSSs[0]); ---> I think this just passes Team's name stored in newSSs[0] to Team's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

From the code snippet it seems you want to store team details in a Team object. However you have many Team objects and you want an array of them. This comes close:

```
ArrayList<Team> teamList = new ArrayList<Team>();
while (lineScanner.hasNextLine())
   {
   currentLine = lineScanner.nextLine();
       String[] newSSs = currentLine.split(","); 
       Team team = new Team(newSS[0]);
       team.setWins(Integer.valueOf(newSS[1]));
       team.setDraws(Integer.valueOf(newSS[2]));
       team.setLoses(Integer.valueOf(newSS[3]));
       team.setPoints(team.calculatePoints());
teamList.add(team);
}
```

[Java 7 ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)
[Java 8 ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: When I use this I get 'actual argument Team[] cannot be converted to Team by method invocation conversion)'